# Aa to Å at reference list

Tags: bibtex, sorting, scandinavian-letters

How do I sort the reference list alphabetic so Aa is at the bottom of the list?

I use bibtex to sort references.

Okay, this is how it looks:

```
\input{preamble} 
\begin{document} 
........ 
\begingroup 
\raggedright 
\bibliographystyle{plain} 
\bibliography{bibtex/litteratur} 
\endgroup 
....... 
\end{document}
```

And then in the bib-file:

```
@manual{Aal, 
  author ={{Aal.......}}, 
  title ={.....}, 
  address={\url{google.dk}}, 
  year ={2014}, 
  note ={Downloadet: 23-02-2015}, 
  sortname = {Ål.....} 
}
```

And its danish

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a sample entry; it would also be helpful if you stated which language you work with. (I assume it's one of the Nordic languages...)

Comment: Bibtex cannot do that as it does not know anything but ascii. Biber+biblatex should be better. Normally I tend to cheat, there is a nosort trick you can use where for example you trick bibtex into thinking this should be sorted as zzzae zzzoe and zzzza but it will print the right letter. You should be able to find it on this dite if you search for it (I'm not at a pc right now, so I cannot make an example)

Comment: Okay, this is how it looks:

\input{preamble}
\begin{document}
........
\begingroup
 \raggedright
 \bibliographystyle{plain}
 \bibliography{bibtex/litteratur}       
\endgroup
.......
\end{document}


And then in the bib-file:

@manual{Aal,
 author ={{Aal.......}},
 title ={.....},
 address={\url{http://www.google.dk}},
 year ={2014},
 note ={Downloadet: 23-02-2015},
 sortname = {Ål.....}
}

And its danish. - daleif could you give an example on that trick?

Comment: @daleif - While it is indeed the case that BibTeX doesn't process non-ASCII characters, it's useful to know that BibTeX sorts author field with non-ASCII surnames after `Z`. It it possible to instruct BibTeX on how to perform the sorting by using the useful `\noopsort` macro, as is explained in the answer below.

Comment: @Mico that was the one I was referring to, just got the name wrong

Comment: @daleif - Thanks for pointing this out. (I must confess I hadn't picked up on in in the initial reading.)

Comment: @Mico, what just happened to your answer?

Comment: @daleif - I deleted it because I don't think it's working correctly.

Comment: @daleif - could you give an example of your trick?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work, remember that bibtex usually does not like utf8 (bibtex8 might cope), I tend to just replace æøå in names and titles with their TeX ascii equivalents `\ae\o\aa`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,danish]{memoir}
\usepackage{babel,url}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{dkbibtest.bib}
@preamble { "\providecommand{\noopsort}[1]{} " }
@article{t1,
  author = {Test Testsen},
  title = {Test 1},
  journal = {Jour 1},
  year = {2016},
}
@article{t2,
  author = {Test {\noopsort{zzza3}\AA rhus}},
  title = {Test 2},
  journal = {Jour 2},
  year = {2016},
}
@article{t3,
  author = {Test {\noopsort{zzza2}\O stergaard}},
  title = {Test 3},
  journal = {Jour 3},
  year = {2016},
}
@article{t4,
  author = {Test {\noopsort{zzza3}Aarhus}},
  title = {Test 4},
  journal = {Jour 4},
  year = {2016},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{dkbibtest}
\end{document}
```

as mentioned in the comments, the idea is to use something that fools the sorting engine. That I've named it `zzza2-3` does not really matter, jsut need to be consistent.

[image]